# How is a group generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having serious problems understanding how a group is generated by some set/group(?).

$\langle a \rangle$ is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$.

Can someone show me a very simple example?

Comment: Consider $(\mathbb Z, +)$ as additive group. Then take for example the element $3\in\mathbb Z$. The generated subgroup is then $<3>=3\mathbb Z=\{....-6,-3,0,3,6,....\}=\{3n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$.

Comment: That makes sense. So let's say...

$$G = (\mathbb{R} / 0 , \cdot)$$

Then if I pick the element $4$ I will generate the subgroup $$H \subseteq G $$ $$H =  4 \mathbb{R} / 0 = \{\ 4n : n \in \mathbb{R} \}\ $$ ?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ with multiplication is not a group since the inverse is missing...

Comment: How about now?.

Comment: @Paze Remember that you always have to work with respect to your group operation; you can't generate $8$ from $4$ in $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$.  Instead, the subgroup of $(\mathbb{R}^+, \cdot)$ generated by $4$ is $\{\ldots, \frac1{16}, \frac14, 1, 4, 16, 64, \ldots\}$.  Does this make sense?

Comment: That is true. I am doing $4^n$. Sorry.

If I change:

$$H = \{\ 4^n : n \in \mathbb{R} \}\ $$ ? isit correct now?

Comment: So now I understand how an element can generate a subgroup. How does a SET generate a group?

Comment: @Paze Let take again the above example $\mathbb Z$ with addition (even though it actually makes no sense  speaking about generatig sets in the context of $\mathbb Z$ but I am sure you will find out why) Consider $\{2,3\}\subset\mathbb Z$. This set generates the whole group i.e $<\{2,3\}>=\{2n:n\in\mathbb Z\}\bigcup\{3n:n\in\mathbb Z\}\bigcup\{1\}=\{...,-2,0,2,4,...\}\bigcup\{...,-3,0,3,6,...\}\bigcup\{1\}$

Comment: Maybe my question was rather: How does a subgroup generate a group?

$HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Hence $$HK = \langle H \cup K \rangle $$

What does this mean exactly? It's the generation of a union of two subgroups...?

Answer (score 1):

Example: $$\langle 2 \rangle  = \{0, 2\} \leq \mathbb Z_4 = \{0, 1, 2 , 3\}$$

On the left we have the subgroup of $\mathbb Z_4$ which is generated by $2$. We find all multiples (since the operation is additive) of $2$, molulo $4$: $2\times 0 = 0$, $2\cdot 1 = 2, 2\cdot 3 = 6 = 2 \mod 4, ... $ and we see we are cycling, so that we have $\langle 2\rangle = \{0, 2\}.$

The group that a group element $h$ generates is precisely those elements which, in the case of an additive group, are multiples of $h$, and in a multiplicative group, powers of $h$. And remember, every group generated by a single element is cyclic, so in finite groups, you will exhaust all of the elements generated by $h$ when the outputs it begins to cycle.

Note that a set can generate a group as well: for example, $(1, 2, 3)$ and $(1, 2)$ generate $\mathbb S_3$.

Here we find that all products of powers of $(1, 2, 3), (1, 2)$ yields precisely the set $\S_3$.

Comment: I might rephrase the last paragraph slightly, since my initial reading of 'all products of powers of $a$ and $b$' would be just the set $\{a^ib^j\}$...

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, a group is generated by a subset if all elements arise as products of elements of the generating set.

More precisely:

First, a *free group* on generators $a_i$ indexed by some set $I$ is defined to be the set of all finite strings $[a_{i_1}^{b_1}...a_{i_k}^{b_1}]$ where $k$ is a natural number, the $b_i$'s are integers and the $i_p$'s are in $I$, with group operation given by concatentation and then simplifying exponentials. For example, on three generators, $[a_1^2 a_2^{-1}]\cdot[a_2 a_1 a_3]=[a_1^3 a_3]$. We say that any group isomorphic to a free group on some number of elements is *free*.

Whenever a group $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient of a free group $F$ by a free normal subgroup $R$, we say that $\langle F|R\rangle$ is a *presentation* of $G$ (we call $R$ the group of *relations* on the generators), and if $F$ is generated by $a_i$ indexed by $I$, we say that the preimages of the $a_i$'s in $G$ are generators for $G$.

As an example, the symmetry group of a triangle, commonly called $S_3$, is the symmetric group on three elements, and is generated by transpositions of two elements at a time:  $\sigma_1:(1,2,3) \mapsto (1,3,2)$, $\sigma_2:(1,2,3)\mapsto (3,2,1)$ and $\sigma_3(1,2,3)\mapsto (2,1,3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example: rotation matrices. Let $n>1$ be a fixed integer. Consider the set of matrices

$$\left\{\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) \\ \sin\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{n}\right)\end{array}\right):0\le k\le n-1\right\}.$$

These form a group under matrix multiplication and are generated by the matrix

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) & -\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) \\ \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right) & \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{n}\right)\end{array}\right).$$

This is easy to see since any of the matrices in our set is just a power of the above matrix.